# How to check the size of a file inside zipped folder in unix?

Tags: shell, file, unix, gzip, php-ziparchive

Is there a way to check the compressed size of files inside a zipped folder, and split files which are greater than 500 KB. The objective is to have a zipped file with multiple files which are less that 500KB each.

Comment: Lots of ways. You could filter the output of `unzip -l`, you could write a Python script using the `zipfile` module; heck, you could use a fuse module to mount the zip file as a filesystem and then use standard UNIX tools like `find` to search its contents. I'd suggest _picking_ a way, trying it yourself, and then asking a question about a narrow, specific problem you encounter during the attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Info-ZIP's open-source zip](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/Zip.html) comes with a utility "zipsplit" that does exactly what you are asking for.